# Isaiah 14 and Ezekiel 28 Interpretation

Tags: textual-criticism

The common interpretation of Isaiah 14 and Ezekiel 28, is telling about Satan and him being cast down.

Has anyone ever hear a different interpretation before?  If so, what was it?

Thank you,

Comment: It isn't just about the event of Lucifer's downfall, it is also God handing over his playbook to humanity in order to deal with him in everday life.

Comment: This scripture is certainly about the daily life of humanity and a grave warning about self exaltation from pride.  I do believe this is a real historical event but it is a metaphor of the downfall of man kind.

Comment: According to Scripture, the devil is a real antagonist, not merely a metaphor for man's corrupt nature. {1 Pet 5:8, Matt 4:1, Matt 5, Gen. 3:1} Recall also 1 Cor 2:14

Answer (score 4):

The word "Satan" (H7854) does not even appear anywhere in the books of Isaiah or Ezekiel.

Isaiah 14:

> 12
> How **you have fallen from heaven**, morning star, son of the dawn! You have been cast down to the earth, you who once laid low the nations!

OP: The common interpretation of Isaiah 14 and Ezekiel 28, is telling about Satan and him being cast down.
Has anyone ever hear a different interpretation before?

Since the word "Satan" never appears in the entire book of Isaiah, this verse is open to non-Satan interpretation.
E.g., Ellicott:

> How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning!--The word for Lucifer is, literally, the shining one, the planet Venus, the morning star, the son of the dawn, as the symbol of the Babylonian power, which was so closely identified with astrolatry. "Lucifer" etymologically gives the same meaning, and is used by Latin poets (Tibull. i., 10, 62) for Venus, as an equivalent for the phosphoros of the Greeks. The use of the word, however, in mediaeval Latin as a name of Satan, whose fall was supposed to be shadowed forth in this and the following verse, makes its selection here singularly unfortunate. Few English readers realise the fact that it is the **king of Babylon, and not the devil, who is addressed as Lucifer**. While this has been the history of the Latin word, its Greek and English equivalents have risen to a higher place, and the "morning star" has become a name of the Christ (Revelation 22:16).

Comment: Very good response Tony. +1

Comment: Thanks. You should run for https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/election/2 :) I'll vote for you :)

Comment: I appreciate the thoughts, Tony. Unfortunately, I don't often downvote someone, even when I feel I should. I'm just not qualified - and I often feel for moderators who must surely endure a mountain of contempt and derision.

Comment: Right. It isn't my cup of tea either :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question. I would suggest that the concepts found in these chapters do not lend themselves to an interpretation that suggests Satan, but instead to the people that are specifically described, which is the king of Babylon and the king of Tyre.

Isaiah 14:4 *that you will take up this proverb against **the king of Babylon***,

Ezekiel 28:2 *"Son of man, say to the **prince of Tyre***...."

It seems that the attribution of the name "Lucifer" ("Morning Star") to Satan did not occur until many centuries after Christ. If one looks at 2 Peter 1:19 we would see that the word Morning Star/Lucifer is actually applied to Christ (or to the Word of Christ), especially seen in the Vulgate translation:

2 Peter 1:19 *And so we have the prophetic word confirmed, which you do well to heed as a light that shines in a dark place, until the day dawns and the **morning star** rises in your hearts*

2 Peter 1:19 *Et habemus firmiorem propheticum sermonem: cui benefacitis attendentes quasi lucernæ lucenti in caliginoso loco donec dies elucescat, et **lucifer** oriatur in cordibus vestris*:

One can see a number of Christians in the first few centuries actually named Lucifer, again testifying to the idea that the name Lucifer was not associated with Satan. Finally, most translations have ceased to use the word "Lucifer" in this passage as it seems contrived

https://www.britannica.com/biography/Lucifer-bishop-of-Cagliari

Comment: thank you for your comments.  On literal side these scriptures are to the two kings.  On the spiritual side I don't these are talking about Satan at all.  Who it is talking about is, Adam and what brought him to sin against the LORD God.  The garden event does not tell us, why he sinned.  the consequences of his action was very grave in bringing sin and death upon humanity.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think that seeing this as Adam is more likely than an application to Satan, but I am not sure that there is a reason to see Adam. Is it the reference to Eden that makes you see this? You might note that Eden is referenced a number of times in prophecy, often describing a nation's prestige (as it does for Egypt in Ezekiel 31). So perhaps is Eden here. Perhaps you also see a motivation for Adam's sin in these passages? I would think that 1 John 2:16 contrasted with Genesis 3:6 might be a stronger correlation.  Again, thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: What makes to think this is Adam is several things.  Yes, the fact he was in Eden.  The person in question is a man, remember that there was three in the garden.  this doesn't include the LORD God.  there was the serpent, the woman and the man Adam.  Isaiah 14:16 indicates that the person was a man.  Ezekiel says he was a man also.

Comment: The person was perfect until iniquity was found in him, what Adam did was iniquity against God and he was without sin until he did sin.  Even Job said he didn't want to hide his iniquity like Adam did. Job 31:33   God said he created evil, and on the sixth day of creation, God created the serpent and Satan.

Answer (score 1):

Let us be very clear about what the text of Isaiah and Ezekiel are actually saying:

- Isa 14:3, 4 - On the day that the LORD gives you rest from your pain and torment, and from the hard labor into which you were forced, you will sing this song of contempt against **the king of Babylon**: How the oppressor has ceased, and how his fury has ended!
- Eze 28:11, 12 - Again the word of the LORD came to me, saying, “Son of man, take up a lament for the **king of Tyre** and tell him that this is what the Lord GOD says: ‘You were the seal of perfection, full of wisdom and perfect in beauty.

If we look at the material in the book of Isaiah we find the above passage is part of a long series against the surrounding nations:

- Isa 13:1 - 14:27 - prophecies against Babylon
- Isa 14:28-32 - prophecy against the Philistines
- Isa 15 & 16 - prophecy against Moab
- Isa 17 - prophecy against Damascus
- Isa 18 - prophecy against Cush
- Isa 19 - prophecy against Egypt
- Isa 20 - prophecy against Egypt and Cush

... and so forth.  There is no doubt that the pronouncements in Isa 14:11ff are directed at the king of Babylon! That is what the text explicitly says.

We have a similar situation in Ezekiel

- Eze 25:1-7 - prophecy against Ammon
- Eze 25:8-11 - prophecy against Moab
- Eze 25:12-14 - prophecy against Edom
- Eze 25:15-17 - prophecy against Philistia
- Eze 26 - prophecy against Tyre
- Eze 27 - lament over Tyre
- Eze 28:1-19 - prophecy against the king of Tyre
- Eze 28:20-26 - prophecy against Sidon
- Eze 29, 30, 31, 32 - prophecy against Egypt

... and so forth.  Again, there is no doubt that the material in Eze 28:12ff is directed against the king of Tyre.  That is what the text explicitly says.

Further in Isa 14:12, the word "Lucifer" does not even exist in the Hebrew (in Heb. it is "Helel" = shining, and in Greek LXX it is ἑωσφόρος (heosphoros) = shining; the word "lucifer" is Latin meaning "shining").  Ellicott observes the "problem" for this verse as unfortunately translated by the KJV -

> (12) How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the
> morning!—The word for Lucifer is, literally, the shining one, the
> planet Venus, the morning star, the son of the dawn, as the symbol of
> the Babylonian power, which was so closely identified with astrolatry.
> “Lucifer” etymologically gives the same meaning, and is used by Latin
> poets (Tibull. i., 10, 62) for Venus, as an equivalent for the
> phôsphoros of the Greeks. The use of the word, however, in mediæval
> Latin as a name of Satan, whose fall was supposed to be shadowed forth
> in this and the following verse, makes its selection here singularly
> unfortunate. Few English readers realise the fact that it is the king
> of Babylon, and not the devil, who is addressed as Lucifer. While this
> has been the history of the Latin word, its Greek and English
> equivalents have risen to a higher place, and the “morning star” has
> become a name of the Christ (Revelation 22:16).

Having said all of the above, since earliest times, the passages in Isa 14:12-15 and  Eze 28:12-17 have been **interpreted** as a **metaphor** of the history of Satan and his fall from heaven as also described in Rev 12:7-9 and Luke 10:18.

How one interprets these passages is quite a separate matter from what the text explicitly says, so let us not forget to allow the Bible to say what it actually says (not what we want it say).

The Pulpit commentary observes this:

> Verse 12. - How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer! Babylon's
> sudden fall is compared, with great force and beauty, to the (seeming)
> fall of a star from heaven. The word translated "Lucifer" means
> properly "shining one," and no doubt here designates a star; but
> whether any particular star or no is uncertain. The LXX. translated by
> ἑωσφόρος, whence our "Lucifer." The subjoined epithet, "son of the
> morning" or "of the dawn," accords well with this rendering. How art
> thou cut down to the ground! One of Isaiah's favorite changes of
> metaphor. It is a favorite metaphor also to which he reverts - that of
> representing the destruction of a nation by the felling of a tree or
> of a forest (comp. Isaiah 2:12, 13; Isaiah 10:33, 34, etc.). Which
> didst weaken the nations; rather, which didst prostrate the nations.
> The word used is one of great force (comp. Exodus 17:13; Job 14:10).
> Isaiah 14:12

The Cambridge commentary correctly observes:

> 12. **O Lucifer; son of the morning** In his splendour he is likened to the morning star; which was worshipped by the Babylonians under the
>     name of Istar, and is described in Assyrian by an epithet, mustilil
>     (shining star), which seems to correspond to the word here used
>     (Schrader, Cuneiform Inscriptions, on this verse). The translation
>     “Lucifer” (light-bearer) is quite correct, and is needlessly abandoned
>     by the R.V. By some of the fathers the passage was applied to the fall
>     of Satan (cf. Luke 10:18); hence the current use of Lucifer as a name
>     of the devil.

Comment: +1 Upvote for stating "How one interprets these passages is quite a separate matter from what the text explicitly says, so let us **Not** forget to allow the Bible to say what it actually says (**Not** what we want it say)."

Answer (score 0):

The only way to [correctly] interpret these two passages is use the correct ‘lens’. Some theologians use an academic lens, and look at it textually. Others try to bring some context into their interpretations - and get closer. There is another ‘pivotal’ aspect, but I’ll introduce that later after overviewing these two first.

Some look for textual evidence - and say the word ‘Satan’ isn’t found. But neither is it found in Genesis - so who was in the garden? In fact, what evidence is there that Satan was even there - and some say he wasn’t. This is a weak counter argument to those who suggest Isaiah/Ezekiel are *not* about Satan. In fact, ‘Satan’ as a ‘proper name’ isn’t found once in the Old Testament.

Now let’s consider context …

**EZEKIEL 28:12** *Son of man, take up a lament concerning the king of Tyre and say to him: ‘This is what the Sovereign Lord says: “‘You were the seal of perfection full of wisdom and perfect in beauty.* **13** *You were in Eden, the garden of God;*

Some claim the ‘king of Tyre’ - *not* Satan? So was this king perfect?, was he in Eden?  These same *still* talk about ‘types and shadows’ elsewhere, but *refuse* to consider it here…. why??

And here in Isaiah, ….

**ISAIAH 14:12** *How you have fallen from heaven, morning star, son of the dawn!*

Who *else* might have, or did ‘fall from heaven? The *only* one the Bible mentions is Satan…

**LUKE 10:18** *He replied, “I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven*

And again we see this ‘fall’ in Revelation 12. And I’ve only taken one verse from these two passages, but could have easily taken several. No, it’s crystal clear who these passages **refer to** - the *emphasis* on ‘refer’ - because these passages use typology. You can *not* ‘just’ use textual analysis.

Now let’s bring in the third aspect, one most theologians don’t. The ‘andient middle eastern’ perspective. And this aspect is very recent, it required the recent archaeological finds, and recent scholarly study of the ancient middle eastern cultures. These passages, in particular Isaiah, are **saturated** with names and typology that *only* make ‘sense’ in *this* context.

Some examples (there are numerous!)

The King of Tyre,  - “*The realm of the dead below is all astir to meet you at your coming; it rouses the spirits of the departed to greet you;*” - “*utmost heights of Mount Zaphon.*”

Theological struggle with ‘bits’ like these. But they all have very clear, and specific meanings - and when *considered*, - leave no doubt that these passages are talking about the *spiritual* realm, and more, specific ‘entities’ that are key ‘figures’ in *that* realm, including the one the New Testament names as Satan.